# UIImageView in UIScrollview is too big

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to show an image using a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollview`. The image needs to fit on the screen while keeping the aspect ratio.

This all works, except that, when I zoom first, I can scroll below the image. The height of area is about 64.

This is how it looks after scrolling (White is the background color of the UIImageView and red is the background color of the UIScrollView):
[image: White is the background color of the UIImageView and red is the background color of the UIScrollView]

This is the code in my ImageViewController:

```
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@interface ImageViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@end

@implementation ImageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0  ;
    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = _imageView.image.size.width / _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    _scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
    _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    _scrollView.delegate = self;
    _imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [_scrollView addSubview:_imageView];

}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.imageView.frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
}

- (UIImageView *)imageView
{
    if (!_imageView) _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    return _imageView;
}

- (UIImage *)image
{
    NSLog(@"image");
    return self.imageView.image;
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSLog(@"setImage");
    self.imageView.image = image;
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

// mandatory zooming method in UIScrollViewDelegate protocol

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}

-(void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    NSLog(@"setImageURL");
    _imageURL = imageURL;
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageURL path]];
}

@end
```

This are the properties of my UIScrollView:

[image: Properties of my UIScrollView]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: That (red) space under the UIImageView. I can scroll under the image, which should not. be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. This is my code:

```
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@interface ImageViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@end

@implementation ImageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    rect.size = self.image.size;
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.5;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    self.imageView.image = self.image;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

}
- (IBAction)tappedAction:(id)sender {
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self.image] applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.imageView.frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
}


#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

// mandatory zooming method in UIScrollViewDelegate protocol

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    UIView *subView = [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

    CGFloat offsetX = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0.0);
    CGFloat offsetY = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0.0);

    subView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,
                                 scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);
}

-(void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    NSLog(@"setImageURL");
    _imageURL = imageURL;
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageURL path]];
}

@end
```

The code in `scrollViewDidZoom:` is used to keep the image centered.